# Variable not in scope: x :: Picture (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

So i'm in the beginning of creating a menu for a game for haskell.

Problem is it does not recognize my BMP files as it gives me this error:

**Variable not in scope: option :: Picture**

```
module Main where

import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Juicy
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game

Estado = Estado {mapaEstado:: Mapa,jogadoresEstado :: [Jogador]}
type EstadoGloss = (Estado,Int,(Picture,(Float,Float)))

janela :: Display
janela = InWindow "Motorbike Race" (1200,700) (0,0)

fps :: Int
fps = 60

estadoInicial :: EstadoGloss
estadoInicial = (Estado [] [],0,(option,(600,400)))

desenhaEstado :: EstadoGloss -> Picture
desenhaEstado (Estado [] [],0,(option,(x,y))) = Translate 600 y option
desenhaEstado (Estado [] [],0,(menu,(x,y))) = Translate 0 0 menu

reageEvento :: Event -> EstadoGloss -> EstadoGloss
reageEvento (EventKey (SpecialKey KeyUp)    Down _ _) (Estado [] [],0,(option,(x,y))) = (Estado [] [],0,(option,(600,y+50)))
reageEvento (EventKey (SpecialKey KeyDown)  Down _ _) (Estado [] [],0,(option,(x,y))) = (Estado [] [],0,(option,(600,y-50))) 
reageEvento _ s = s 

reageTempo :: Float -> EstadoGloss -> EstadoGloss
reageTempo tempo estg = estg

main :: IO ()
main = do
          menu <- loadBMP "menu.bmp"
          option <- loadBMP "option.bmp"
          bike <- loadBMP "bike.bmp"

          play janela         
               aquamarine      
               fps            
               estadoInicial   
               desenhaEstado   
               reageEvento    
               reageTempo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you wrote `option <- loadBMP "option.bmp"` in your main action doesn't mean it's automatically in scope everywhere in your program. It *can't* be, because the value can only exist after you've performed the IO of reading it from the file, so particularly not in pure functions / values like `estadoInicial`!

What you need to do is, pass it on explicitly as a parameter.

```
estadoInicial :: Picture -> EstadoGloss
estadoInicial option = (Estado [] [],0,(option,(600,400)))

...

main :: IO ()
main = do
      menu <- loadBMP "menu.bmp"
      option <- loadBMP "option.bmp"
      bike <- loadBMP "bike.bmp"

      play janela         
           aquamarine      
           fps            
           (estadoInicial option)
           desenhaEstado   
           reageEvento    
           reageTempo
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't give a line number, I think it happens here:

```
estadoInicial = (Estado [] [],0,(option,(600,400)))
```

You declare `option` in the main block, but then you never pass it to `estadoInicial`. If you want to use it there you need to pass it as a parameter as you do in your declaration for `desenhaEstado`.